# APK Can't Install on Any Mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk, apk-expansion-files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7OHk.png)I developped an Android Mobile Application, and extract APK fro Android studio but when I send APK to other Mobiles ,, a Message display message say cannot install this APK ..Could any[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVzle.png)one help me where is the Problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: have you correctly generate your apk

Comment: which message??? dispaer to me

Comment: In the image app name is app-debug.rar.. is it correct or you have compressed the apk file.. it should be app-debug.apk

Comment: I generated APK and it run successfuly on my mobile but when i send it to another mobile it cann't run

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any detail information. So I guess...

1. minSDK - 24 / real device - 21 -> You can not install.  
   you should check your minSDK from your build.gradle.
2. appropriate building : menu -> Build -> Build APK.
   then you can find your APK from "YourProject\app\build\outputs"

Comment: I edited the sdk from 19 to 24 as you said .. but where's the real device ?

Comment: nono... your minSDK should be lower than your real device(the device you have)

Comment: My devicee is 4.4.2 .. whick sdk suitable to this ?? and how do i know that later

Comment: [check this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: what about Code Version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install you APK on the same device that you can already run your app from android studio, if there'll be an error then generate your apk correctly, or if there'll be no errors then it should be from device version, change you minSDK version from gradle

try to change minSdkVersion 15

Comment: It's Run successfuly on my device but not installed on any aother device

Comment: can you send me your gradle file

Comment: and what is the device you are running on?

Comment: I run this App on device version 4.4.2 kitkat android and API 19

Comment: change minSdkVersion 15

Answer (score 0):

Usually this occurs when there is an unchecked runtime error in the code or if the compile version is different from the Mobile.

Also you should check your AndroidManifest to see if here maybe a services used in the code that are not requisitioned in the manifest file

Comment: what suitable CodeVersion should I put in gradle ??

Comment: this is totally up to you. Choose a version that you are comfortable with. it usually one for which the compiler is present on your system. but if i was to recommend on it would be minSDK version 15